# Php and Java back end

Tags: php

I like php, and I'm beginning to like java.  I heard that jsp is officially deprecated (on the oracle website) and I'm trying to figure out how I could get data from a php script (from field data, image uploads) send it to my java program and have the results sent back to my php script.

Now I know I could use php for *everything* but some websites (such as google) use multiple back ends such as C and python.

Comment: why would you like to do that? you could just use a java web application framework instead of wrapping java into php code. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_application_frameworks#Java

Comment: Because I want to use php, not exclusive java.  And, JSP is depricated on the website, so I kinda have the feeling I shouldn't use it.  Jsp server hosting is also quite expensive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several possibilities to interface PHP and Java. To name a few you coud try:

- Make a Webservice in Java and [call this Webservice in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/book.soap.php).
- Use another RPC protocol, like [Thrift](http://thrift.apache.org/).
- There is also the [PHP/Java bridge](http://php-java-bridge.sourceforge.net/pjb/).
- [Quercus](http://www.caucho.com/resin-3.0/quercus/) is a PHP implementation in Java. When using this, you can just write functions in Java and call them from PHP.
- PHP has [experimental support for integrating Java](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.java.php).

Comment: This looks quite interesting, I'll have a look at it